# How to preview front-end of Checkout Sucess Page by order id

Tags: magento2, module, onepage-checkout, order-success-page

I'm working on a module that styles the checkout success page. It's already done. I want to have a function preview in the back-end of my module that when you enter an order id and click preview, it will display the check out success page of that order in a pop-up or new tab.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_CheckoutTester2
Yiero has one for both Magento 1 & 2 that are with looking into.

Comment: Thank you, it works. but one problem. when i reload the page, the url of frontend change to admin with key. I think this is from cache. but I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Reporting the issue on GitHub may get you a better answer, as it may be a bug with the module.